# Angular error object thrown upon $http.post request

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am setting up a new angular app and encountered a strange error anytime I tried to make am ajax request with $http.

I have the following code:

```
srnApp.controller('WallCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http.post('/api',  {
            "method":"wallStuff"
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("SUCCESS retrieving wall: \n", data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("ERROR getting wall: \n", data, status, headers, config);
        });
]);
```

Every time the request is made I get the following error object before the error callback is called:

```
Exception { 
    message: "", 
    result: 2153644038, 
    name: "", 
    filename: "myServer.net/js/angular.min.js", 
    lineNumber: 78, 
    columnNumber: 0, 
    inner: null, 
    data: null 
}
```

What exactly does this mean and how can I work around it?

Comment: I have a couple suggestions. First, change from minified angular to non-minified. This will point you to a human-readable error. Second, avoid using "method" as a parameter since angular uses 'method' in $http.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. My resource was not the same as the place from which the js was served so the browser would not allow the request. I fixed this by changing some server side stuff.

Comment: Basically you have to make ajax/http requests to the same domain from which the page you are at came from.

Comment: I have only one domain and request target is relative to it "/api/...". Problem reproduced on a customer side, I can't reproduce problem in my inviroment...